# Can some one suggest a method to know the incoming transactions in a nodes addresses?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am trying to figure out a solution to find if there is any update in wallet address in my node i am using web3py.

Answer (score 0):

Jist use web3.eth.getBlock (blocknumber). You will get all the transaction hash inside block. Then use web3.eth.getTransaction (txhash) to get the tx recipt and match whether your address have some transactions.